# how to SQL query with conditioned distinct

Tags: sql

Simple Database:

```
street     | age
1st st     | 2
2nd st     | 3
3rd st     | 4
3rd st     | 2
```

I'd like to build a query that'll return the DISTINCT street names, but only for those households where no one is over 3.

so that result would be:

```
 street        | age
    1st st     | 2
    2nd st     | 3
```

How do I do that? I know of DISTINCT, but now how to conditionalize it for all the records that match the DISTINCT

Comment: Must the expected result include the `age` field?

Comment: no. i was just showing it for illustration

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I'm using postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the name of the table is 'tab'. You can then try:

```
select distinct street from tab where street not in (select street from tab where age>3);
```

I have created a sql fiddle where you can view the result:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c513d/2

Answer (score 0):

Distinct street names for households where no one is over 3:

```
SELECT street
FROM table
GROUP BY street
HAVING COUNT(1) <= 3
```

Comment: @downvoter care to comment on why the downvote? This was the first answer and accurately gives the user what he is asking

Answer (score 0):

USE `GROUP BY`

```
Select Street
from yourtable
group by street
Having sum(age)<=3
```

Another way this could be achived with a use of `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT street
     FROM yourtable b
     WHERE age > 3
       AND a.street = b.street)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT street 
FROM table 
WHERE NOT(age>3)
```

Comment: will that on "1 main st" if there are 10 records with "1 main st" but ages varying from 3 to 50? i think not.

Comment: Yes, it will produce one record on "1 main st" for the household with age=3.